# Show Website Switcher on Header in Magento 2

Tags: multi-website, magento-2.0.9

I need to add website selector on my Magento 2 site header. I am using Magento 2.0.9. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get website name and url using this snippet.

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}

public function getWebsites() 
{
    $_websites = $this->_storeManager->getWebsites();
    $_websiteData = array();
    foreach($_websites as $website){
        foreach($website->getStores() as $store){
            $wedsiteId = $website->getId();
            $storeObj = $this->_storeManager->getStore($store);
            $name = $website->getName();
            $url = $storeObj->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
            array_push($_websiteData, array('name' => $name,'url' => $url));
        }
    }

    return $_websiteData;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Patel. I have tried this method, it worked fine. One change that I have made is, here you are fetching store name I changed it to `$name = $website->getName();` .

Comment: Ok, Sure. I need one more help. I have created a block to list this. Could you please suggest me a way to display it in the header. I want to know the XML format.

Comment: I also want website switcher on my header. In which should I put this code? In switch/stores.phtml ?

Comment: Above code is for Block file.

Comment: ok, how can I make block file for Magento2? where can I find an instruction?