# Website switcher on Magento2?

Tags: magento2, multistore, switcher, multi-website

I would like to place a website switcher in the header.
I checked this but not sure in which file to place the code..

[Show Website Switcher on Header in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145137/show-website-switcher-on-header-in-magento-2)

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you created multi website and you have used custom theme?

Comment: yes, and I made as a child theme.

Answer (score 0):

Website Switcher functionality you can add in header section same as store switcher. I have not created that drop down but I have found one module to automatically switch website using customer current GEO IP address. Please review below link.
http://www.logicrays.com/store/magento-2-extensions/multi-website-switcher.html